# How allow or prevent aws iam users to run sendCommand?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have created a aws_iam_policy_document with ssm and ec2 actions :

```
data "aws_iam_policy_document" "AdminEc2Actions" {
  statement {
    effect    = "Allow"
    sid = "sid1"
    actions = [
        "ssm:SendCommand",
        "ec2:Start*",
        "ssm:StartSession"
    ]
    resources = [
      "*"
    ]    
  }   
}

# Create IAM policy for ec2
resource "aws_iam_policy" "AdminEc2Actions" {
  name                = "test-AdminEc2Actions-policies"
  description         = "ec2 policies"
  path                = "/"
  policy              = data.aws_iam_policy_document.AdminEc2Actions.json
}
# Attaches customer managed IAM poloicy to an IAM admins group 
resource "aws_iam_group_policy_attachment" "AdminEc2Actions" {
  group               = aws_iam_group.groups[0].name
  policy_arn          = aws_iam_policy.AdminEc2Actions.arn 
}
```

But, for some reason, any changes in actions sometimes are taken into account sometimes are  ignored. eg. when I run this command, I got :

```
[ssm-user@ip-xxx.yy.zz.1]$ aws s3 mv /tmp/file* s3://test-dent-backup1/daily/
move failed: ../../tmp/file1.txt to s3://test-dent-backup1/daily/file1.txt [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/file1.txt'
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Seems like this is linux file permission  issue, not IAM.

Comment: Hello, I have even changes permission of file.txt using chmod 777 vut still giving [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/file1.txt'

Comment: The error says its `file1.txt`, not `file.txt`. Maybe you keep changing permissions of the wrong file.

Comment: Hello Marcin, that's because I'm testing with diff. files. I have checked again and no issue with linux permissions : `[ssm-user@ip tmp]$ sudo chmod 777 file1.txt
[ssm-user@ip tmp]$ aws s3 mv /tmp/file* s3://test-dent-backup1/daily/
move failed: ./file1.txt to s3://test-dent-backup1/daily/file1.txt [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/file1.txt' `

Comment: My use case is the following:
`1.   group dev  : user1, user2 2.   group prod : user5, user6 3. Allow group dev to run SSMcommand 4. Prevent group prod to run SSMcommand`
How we can do it using terrafom ?

Comment: Does your instance have instance role with S3 putObject permissions?

Comment: yes. This is how it's declared :  `data "aws_iam_policy_document" "s3" {
  version = "2012-10-17"
  statement {
    #sid = ""
    effect = "Allow"
    actions = ["sts:AssumeRole"]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["ec2.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}

data "aws_iam_policy" "s3" {
  arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonS3FullAccess" # TO DO : check less right access 
}`